# When should I use usize vs i32, f32?

Tags: rust, numbers, precision

I'm modelling JSON objects as structs:

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
}
```

How do I know when I should use `usize` vs `i32`, `f32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what data you want to store:

**`usize`**: a [pointer-sized integer type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html), which means that the size of the integer stored depends on how many bytes are needed to store a reference in a pointer into memory. For a 32-bit machine this is 4 bytes and for a 64-bit machine it's 8 bytes.

**`i32`**: a [32-bit integer type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html). In many programming languages this is the default size for integers like `int` or `Integer`.

**`f32`**: a [32-bit floating point type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html). In many programming langues this type is known as `float`, whereas `f64` is known as double.